# re.sub doen't change values into document word

Tags: python

I have this:

```py
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    if 'TEXT_IN_DOC' in paragraph.text:
        for i in range(0,len(dfs)):
            paragraph.text=re.sub("TEXT_IN_DOC", Company_Name[i], paragraph.text) 
            doc.save('Company'+Company_Name[i]+'.docx')
```

It works only when it saves the name of the document, each document will have the name of the company correctly, but when it changes the paragraph all the files have the first variable and it doesn't change

Example:
First document: `File Name: Company_1 into file Company_1`

Second document: `File Name: Company_2 into file Company_1`

Comment: why do you save outside `for i` loop if you use `i` in filename ?

Comment: It's in the loop the save. Wrong transciption